# Deploying applet with 3rd party library

Tags: java, applet, classpath

I am trying to use gson library with my applet but JRE(8u25) does not see the library and gives me this error:
[image]

**MyAppSigned.jar** is my signed applet
**gson-2.3.1.jar** is the library i am trying to use

**Test WebPage Content (Test.html):**

```
<html>
<body>
<applet code='test.XApplet' width=400  height=400>
    <param name='ARCHIVE' value='MyAppSigned.jar,gson-2.3.1.jar'>
    <param name='codebase' value='http://example.com/Commons'>
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the content of the manifest file inside MyAppSigned.jar:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Trusted-Library: true
Class-Path: gson-2.3.1.jar
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: 1.6.0_26 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Codebase: *
Name: test/XApplet.class
SHA1-Digest: qLHEgL7Or0Ja7Jn7iRZt2lJ/928=
```

**Here is the content of commons directory on iis:**
[image]

I tried with/without codebase attribute in my test webpage. it does not changed the error.
But if i copy gson-2.3.1.jar into the directory *C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\lib\ext* **it Works without any error**

**what am i doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

First of all copy the jar in `JRE_HOME/lib/ext`is not a good solution since then you've to copy this jar in all the client machines which will use your applet.

I think that the problem with your code is in your `<applet>` definition, you're using `<param>` to define `archive`, however in documentation `archive` and others are defined as attributes of `<applet>` tag, take a look at [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/using_tags.html). So try defining the `<applet>` as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<applet code="test.XApplet" width="400"  height="400" 
    archive="MyAppSigned.jar,gson-2.3.1.jar" codebase="http://example.com/Commons">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that it's better to use `<object>` since `<applet>` tag will not be supported in `HTML5`, also think about [use `deployJava.js`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html) which can make more easy to deploy an applet in a different browsers.

Hope this helps,

Comment: i know i just writed that to give extra info. I tried the html code you give, still i am getting the same error.

Comment: on console i am seeing this.     network: Downloaded http://example.com/commons/gson-2.3.1.jar: C:\Users\BAHADI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jar_cache7646433364735176176.tmp
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://example.com/commons/gson-2.3.1.jar
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@2b6ecfbd: 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonParser

Comment: @e13420xx it's wired, only to be sure: both `jars` are available at the url specified by `codebase`? I suppose that they are because in your traces there is `network: Downloaded example.com/commons...` ,However can you download manually and check if the `jar` is correct and has `com/google/gson/JsonParser` class, only to check that it's not corrupted. Another option is to clean the java plugin cache since you're developing maybe there is something wrong in cache, go to `java control panel > general tab > Internet temp files > Configuration...` clean all archives and try again. Hope this helps

Comment: Jar is not corrupted and has the mentioned package since the app works when i copy the jar on jre/bin/ext folder. Yes i van download the archives from my browser

Comment: Then I suppose that you already try to delete the cache... now I don't have more guesses sorry `:(`.

Comment: yes i delete the cache and i also select "dont keep temp files on my computer". Nothing has changed. Anyway thank you for all your help.